# get a href attribute and set this attribute to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 classes with such a structure (this is slider in my web app):

```
<div class="emotion--digital-publishing">
  <div class="dig-pub">
    <div class="bg--image">/div>
      <div class="dig-pub--layer center center">
        <div class="layer--wrapper">
          <div class="layer--content">
            <div class="dig-pub--button">
              <a href="/wilson-camo"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to get `href` attribute of `a` and set a `href` atribute with **this** url to `dig-pub`. It is very important to me that this is the link (which class I clicked), because 3 classes have different links.
   I would like to use jQuery.

Comment: You want to store the href of <a> on <div class="dig-pub"?

Comment: yes, but this is must a *this* href.

Comment: Please show us the JavaScript/jQuery you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Don't forget to close the div on line 3 in your snippet)

```
jQuery('.dig-pub').on('click', function() {
   url = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');
   jQuery(location).attr(url);
});
```

https://codepen.io/Kidkie/pen/gdaJjZ

Comment: Thank u, this is work perfectly! But I have a additional question: `window.open(url);` open this href in new window. I would like to open this href a normal. (toggle the site)

Comment: The code above opens in the same window! It's just the Codepen version that doesn't. If you look at the javascript the code is there, just commented away...

Answer (score 2):

You bind a click event to your anchor tag. you'll need to assign a class to the anchor tag too if you have many on the page so replace 'className' with your class name. I'm not sure how you want to assign it to the div so I've done it as a data-attribute as this is the conventional way to go.

```
$('a.className').on('click', function (){
    $(this).closest('.dig-pub').attr('data-href', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Sometimes, a JSFiddle is worth a thousand words ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First, add an id to the link and the div (easier to fetch the elements)

```
<div id="dig-pub" class="dig-pub">
<a id="id" href="/wilson-camo"></a>
```

Then, get the href

```
var href = $('#id').attr('href');
```

Set the value to the div

```
$('#dig-pub').html(href);
```

However, you could have find this easily on JQuery documentation.